# What does this error mean?

Tags: fedora

What does the following error mean and how can I fix the problem?  THis is on Fedora 9:

```
Time:         Wed Sep 30 10:07:18 2009 -0400
Account:      haldaemon
Resource:     Process Time 
Exceeded:     461956 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/libexec/hald-addon-keyboard
Command Line: hald-addon-keyboard: listening on /dev/input/event1
PID:          3112
Killed:       No
```

G-Man

Comment: What is this output from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the report from some process monitor. It was triggered because the length of time exceeded the threshold: 461956 > 1800.

HAL is the Hardware Abstraction Layer. I believe the hald-addon-keyboard means that this is the process listening to the keyboard for key presses.

I don't think this is a problem, this is some sort of exemption you need to add into your monitoring software, since it is a legit process to be running in the background.

Comment: Thanks - how can I find out what the monitoring software is that's being used?

Comment: How are you receiving this error?

Comment: It's coming to me in an email.